# error C2011: 'SelectorBox' : 'class' type redefinition

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors

I have a problem with a following code:

```
 #ifndef HEADER_H_

    class SelectorBox{
    public:
        string selectorName;  
        map < string, string > attributeMap;
        void setSelectorName(string name);   
        void setAttribute(string key, string value); 
    };
    string trimTheString(string str); //trimming a string
    #endif

//include libraries 
#include "Header.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector <SelectorBox> vectorSelectBox;
    SelectorBox *selectorBox;

//code
return 0;
}

#include "Header.h"
#include "main.cpp"

void SelectorBox::setSelectorName(string name)   //setter
{
    name = trimTheString(name);
    selectorName = name;
}

void SelectorBox::setAttribute(string key, string value)  //setter
{
    key = trimTheString(key);
    value = trimTheString(value);
    attributeMap[key] = value;
}
```

When I compile a program, it shows many errors (specifically errors 4430 and 2061), but I believe that the main error is:
error C2011: 'SelectorBox' : 'class' type redefinition.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: **How many files** are we talking about?

Comment: In which file did you place the line `#include "main.cpp"`?

Comment: @Wolf OP probably has multiple files yet not showing the MCVE.

Comment: Make clear which code belongs to which file, I mean: name the snippets!

Answer (score 1):

You are including the same header twice, first before `main` second after `main`, this causes a problem if you don't use proper include guards.

Your [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) is incomplete, so multiple includes of the same header will cause this error. The trick is to check if a header-specific preprocessor name is defined: If not, then define it, else skip the whole header.

The pattern to use is like this

```
#ifndef GUARD
#define GUARD
/// the actual header contents
#endif
```

but simply copying it into every header will cause another problem, because its lack of header specificity. The simplest way to find a good name is to derive it from the file name itself. In your case I'd name the header after the class `SelectorBox` defined in it, so `SelectorBox.h` would be a good name, and the include guards would look like this:

```
#ifndef SELECTORBOX_H
#define SELECTORBOX_H

class SelectorBox {
/// etc.
};

#endif
```

Using multiple headers with the same include guard is much worse than using no include guards at all.

Comment: Tried it and it is not helping. Also tried to use #pragma once instead, but it is not helping ether.

Comment: @gusev You are including the same header twice.

Comment: The next problem is that you include `main.cpp`, hopefully not within `main.cpp` itself ;)

Answer (score 1):

You must define `HEADER_H_`. You missed second line from below code.

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_
...
#endif
```

Comment: Tried it and it is not helping. Also tried to use #pragma once instead, but it is not helping ether.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you have 3 files:

- `Header.h`
- `main.cpp`
- `FileX.cpp` (you didn't disclose the real name of mister X so far)

In `main.cpp` you are including `Header.h`, in `FileX.cpp` you are including `Header.h` and `main.cpp`. Let me show a simplified version of what happens here:

The contents of `main.cpp` gets transformed into

```
//include libraries 
class SelectorBox{
public:
    string selectorName;  
    map < string, string > attributeMap;
    void setSelectorName(string name);   
    void setAttribute(string key, string value); 
};
string trimTheString(string str); //trimming a string

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector <SelectorBox> vectorSelectBox;
    SelectorBox *selectorBox;

//code
return 0;
}
```

Assuming you included `string` and `map` and there is another `using namespace std;` somewhere before your class definition, this could compile without errors.

But now let's see what happens in `FileX.cpp`. Its contents gets transformed into the following, and I hope you'll see now what the compilers sees: there is **more than one definition** of the class `SelectorBox`:

```
class SelectorBox{
public:
    string selectorName;  
    map < string, string > attributeMap;
    void setSelectorName(string name);   
    void setAttribute(string key, string value); 
};
string trimTheString(string str); //trimming a string
//include libraries 
class SelectorBox{
public:
    string selectorName;  
    map < string, string > attributeMap;
    void setSelectorName(string name);   
    void setAttribute(string key, string value); 
};
string trimTheString(string str); //trimming a string

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector <SelectorBox> vectorSelectBox;
    SelectorBox *selectorBox;

//code
return 0;
}

void SelectorBox::setSelectorName(string name)   //setter
{
    name = trimTheString(name);
    selectorName = name;
}

void SelectorBox::setAttribute(string key, string value)  //setter
{
    key = trimTheString(key);
    value = trimTheString(value);
    attributeMap[key] = value;
}
```

... compilers use to call that a **"redefinition"**.